# Checking array for duplicate of 2 objects

Tags: php

I have a small program sunning that reads in a csv file with customers and their bookings and places them into a nested array, I have already sorted some of the data, but now need to make sure that there isn't any customers booking for the same date and time (also is it possible to check that the time is at least 30 min apart, all the times are in 30 min increments) I've tried a simple in_array method and got nothing tried a few other ways and didn't get any where, any ideas how I could do this. $date[5] is the dates and $data[6] is the time, the data is all strings.

```
if (($h = fopen("{$filename}", "r")) !== FALSE) {
   //each line in the file is converted into its own individual array
   while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !==FALSE) {
       //check if anyone has tried to book for unavailable dates, weekends, last day of the month etc 
        if (!in_array($data[5], $Adates)) {
            $contact[] = $data;
        }
        //this checks if the person is trying to make a booking before 9am or after 6pm
        elseif ((($data[6]) < "09:00") || (($data[6]) > "18:00")) {
            $contact[] = $data;
        } else {
            $College1[] = $data; 
        }
         
        if (in_array($data[5], $College1) 
            && in_array($data[6],$College1)) {
            $College2[] = $College1;
        }
```

Heres a sample of some of the test data i used (there is over 30 customers) :

```
T1,Aleshia,Tomkiewicz,atomkiewicz@hotmail.com,01835-703597,03/11/2020,11:30,P256
T2,Evan,Zigomalas,evan.zigomalas@gmail.com,01937-864715,12/11/2020,15:00,P146
T3,France,Andrade,france.andrade@hotmail.com,01347-368222,30/11/2020,08:30,P68
```

Comment: "$date[5] is the dates and $data[6] is the time, the data is all strings."  change that to have dates and times. It is a lot easier to work with than strings. Also, when you are actually storing dates in a string, then use the format "yyyyMMdd" and never any other format. This makes it (at least) possible to sort on these things.

Comment: No idea whats in `$Adates` or `$College1` So would help to know this

Comment: Hopefully those aren't real emails

Comment: "that reads in a csv file with customers and their bookings...make sure that there isn't any customers booking for the same date" - in terms of application design, this is a fractal horror story.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your code, I guess you could improve your elseif manipulating the time string, getting just the hour and comparing that number as an int.

```
elseif ((($data[6]) < "09:00") || (($data[6]) > "18:00"))

$hrBooked = (int) explode(':', $data[6])[0]; // This should be placed before the main if
elseif (( $hrBooked < 9) || $hrBooked > 18))
```

Looking at your code, I think you'll benefit from using the [DateTime PHP class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for all your checks and comparisons.